# composer generate [JsonSchema\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException] while executing any command

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I am using `composer` with `php 7.1.5` on `Windows 10 (x64)`, I am able to update `composer` itself if the current folder is empty but as soon as I create `composer.json` for the project (`composer init`) then any `composer command` will fail with the same error. Deleting `composer.json` will make that error disappear.

```
[JsonSchema\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException] 
  file_get_contents(phar://Y:/Programs cache/PHP/): 
  failed to open stream: phar error: no directory in "phar://Y:/Programs cache/PHP/", 
  must have at least phar://Y:/Programs cache/PHP// for root directory
  (always use full path to a new phar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue, I just have a "`#`" in the paths, I know that this char cause a lot of issues when used in folder names but the problem is that `composer` worked normally for the update but stopped when I tried `composer init`